# Why are my gravity form checkboxes and labels out of alignment?

Tags: css, wordpress, checkbox, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm a gravity form newbie and I inherited this site from the previous web developer. I notice that my gravity form checkboxes are out of alignment and being placed above the labels.

I googled a few different CSS edits but none of them seem to work. The hardest part here is that because I inherited the site, I'm not even sure where to begin with sussing out the problematic bit of code.

I tried inserting the following into my custom css to force it to work, but it does not:

```
.gform_wrapper .gfield_checkbox li label, .gform_wrapper .gfield_radio li label {
display: inline-block;
}
```

I don't have any html code because the site is ultimately a wordpress site and there's a ton of CSS in the stylesheet D:

I believe this is all the related code:

https://pastebin.com/EYp5d41H

Comment: Do add your html codes and relative css codes as well to help us get a better understanding and the ability to debug your problem and NOT the link to your work.

Comment: [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is happening because of the **break tag** (`<br>` tag). Which is being added from the gravity form.

Please remove the break tags and then add your css. It will be aligned properly.

[image]

Comment: I'm having this exact same issue after the most recent Gravity form update. Something is now inserting the `<br>` tags between the input field and label. Has anyone figured out what is causing this?

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps as a stop gap, this'll stop the display of the break. Judging by the views I guess there's a few of us that need a quick, albeit nasty, fix.

```
.gform_wrapper br { display: none; }
```

Found here if you want the context: http://kaptinlin.com/support/discussion/11960/gravity-forms-how-to-remove-unwanted-br-and-p-tags-striking-original-theme-use-raw-tags/p1